# got Notice message when submit form in html

Tags: php, html

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action="" method="GET">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
  Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
  <input type="submit" />
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
<?php
  if( $_GET["name"] || $_GET["age"] )
  {
     echo "Welcome ". $_GET['name']. "<br />";
     echo "You are ". $_GET['age']. " years old.";
  }
?>
```

Question:

when I open above script in browser, It shows:Notice: `Undefined index: name in D:\wamp\www\oop\test3.php on line 13,` 
I know if is because the form is not submit yet, so `$_GET["name"]` does not exist, but how to fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the name of the submit button, and use `isset()` to check if the form was submitted.

```
<html>
    <body>
      <form action="" method="GET">
          Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
          Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" />
      </form> 
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    if( isset($_GET['submit']) )
    {
        echo "Welcome ". $_GET['name']. "<br />";
        echo "You are ". $_GET['age']. " years old.";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The example below will check if both fields are filled.

If one or the other is not filled, an error message will appear.

If both are filled, then the user will see:

**Welcome Bob**  // assuming the person's name is "Bob" in the field.
**You are 30 years old.** // assuming the person entered "30" in the field.

Otherwise, it will echo:

**Fill in all fields.**

Here is the example below:

```
<html>
    <body>
      <form action="" method="GET">
          Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
          Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" />
      </form> 
    </body>
</html>

<?php


if($_GET['name'] && $_GET['age'])

    {
        echo "Welcome ". $_GET['name']. "<br />";
        echo "You are ". $_GET['age']. " years old.";
    }

if(!$_GET['name'] || !$_GET['age'])

    {

        echo "Fill in all fields";

    }

?>
```

I've made use of both `&&` and `||` logical operators for validation.

Consult the PHP manual for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 0):

You can test if your particular `_GET` variable exists. For example:

```
<?php
if ( isset ( $_GET["name"] ) ) {
    echo "Welcome ". $_GET['name']. "<br />";          
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: How does adding an ID change anything server side?

Comment: I was thinking the problem was with the form variable.  No need to get all crazy with a down vote, it was just something to try.